# Ovpn file integration with android

Tags: android, android-studio, vpn, openvpn, ics-openvpn

I have to access this file in the android studio on how to integrate this file.

I see this code on GitHub but I am not able to understand very much from this code.
Project link which I refer
[Github project](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn)

anyone can help me in simple steps

Comment: please be more clear regarding what you want to achieve. Usually .ovpn file is used to connect your device to a VPN. Usually you use a different application to interact with it. like the one you sent link to.

Comment: I want to make this type of application which user can use ovpn file and connect vpn

Comment: My guess is that this type of application are basically UI and wrappers around the original openvpn service (probably adding some plugins). Note that there is an official openvpn for android application. The openvpn protocol is very complex so trying to implement it yourself is very hard and in my opinion not needed when the service is open sourced